# Error when access vcloud via jcloud

Tags: jclouds, vcloud-director-rest-api

I got the following error when I tried to access VClouds using Jcloud. What would be the possible reason for this eror?
When I accessed the url `https://something.com/api/admin/org/89925701-f1f9-406d-8c9f-26b1f7ca6843/catalogs` using the browser, it desplays

> No valid API version can be selected

2013-08-06 17:15:54,416 ERROR AllCatalogsInOrg [user thread 4] 
catalogs in `username`, completed: 0/3, errors: 1, rate: 35ms/op
org.jclouds.vcloud.VCloudResponseException: request GET https://something.com/api/admin/org/89925701-f1f9-406d-8c9f-26b1f7ca6843/catalogs HTTP/1.1 failed with code 405, error: [majorErrorCode=405, message=HTTP method not allowed, minorErrorCode=METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, stackTrace=null, vendorSpecificErrorCode=null]
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.handlers.ParseVCloudErrorFromHttpResponse.handleError(ParseVCloudErrorFromHttpResponse.java:74)
    at org.jclouds.http.handlers.DelegatingErrorHandler.handleError(DelegatingErrorHandler.java:69)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService$HttpResponseCallable.shouldContinue(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:197)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService$HttpResponseCallable.call(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:167)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService$HttpResponseCallable.call(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at org.jclouds.concurrent.config.DescribingExecutorService.submit(DescribingExecutorService.java:89)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.submit(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:132)
    at org.jclouds.http.TransformingHttpCommandExecutorServiceImpl.submit(TransformingHttpCommandExecutorServiceImpl.java:54)
    at org.jclouds.http.TransformingHttpCommandImpl.execute(TransformingHttpCommandImpl.java:73)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.AsyncRestClientProxy.createListenableFutureForHttpRequestMappedToMethodAndArgs(AsyncRestClientProxy.java:248)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.AsyncRestClientProxy.invoke(AsyncRestClientProxy.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.getCatalog(Unknown Source)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.AllCatalogsInOrg$1.apply(AllCatalogsInOrg.java:64)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.AllCatalogsInOrg$1.apply(AllCatalogsInOrg.java:1)
    at org.jclouds.concurrent.FutureIterables.transformParallel(FutureIterables.java:98)
    at org.jclouds.concurrent.FutureIterables.transformParallel(FutureIterables.java:86)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.AllCatalogsInOrg.apply(AllCatalogsInOrg.java:60)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.AllCatalogsInOrg.apply(AllCatalogsInOrg.java:1)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.AllCatalogItemsInOrg.apply(AllCatalogItemsInOrg.java:50)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.AllCatalogItemsInOrg.apply(AllCatalogItemsInOrg.java:1)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.VAppTemplatesInOrg.apply(VAppTemplatesInOrg.java:56)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.VAppTemplatesInOrg.apply(VAppTemplatesInOrg.java:1)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.suppliers.VAppTemplatesSupplier$1$1.call(VAppTemplatesSupplier.java:82)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.suppliers.VAppTemplatesSupplier$1$1.call(VAppTemplatesSupplier.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at org.jclouds.concurrent.config.DescribingExecutorService.submit(DescribingExecutorService.java:89)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.submit(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:132)
    at org.jclouds.http.TransformingHttpCommandExecutorServiceImpl.submit(TransformingHttpCommandExecutorServiceImpl.java:54)
    at org.jclouds.http.TransformingHttpCommandImpl.execute(TransformingHttpCommandImpl.java:73)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.AsyncRestClientProxy.createListenableFutureForHttpRequestMappedToMethodAndArgs(AsyncRestClientProxy.java:248)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.AsyncRestClientProxy.invoke(AsyncRestClientProxy.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.getCatalog(Unknown Source)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.AllCatalogsInOrg$1.apply(AllCatalogsInOrg.java:64)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.AllCatalogsInOrg$1.apply(AllCatalogsInOrg.java:1)
    at org.jclouds.concurrent.FutureIterables.transformParallel(FutureIterables.java:98)
    at org.jclouds.concurrent.FutureIterables.transformParallel(FutureIterables.java:86)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.AllCatalogsInOrg.apply(AllCatalogsInOrg.java:60)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.AllCatalogsInOrg.apply(AllCatalogsInOrg.java:1)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.AllCatalogItemsInOrg.apply(AllCatalogItemsInOrg.java:50)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.AllCatalogItemsInOrg.apply(AllCatalogItemsInOrg.java:1)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.VAppTemplatesInOrg.apply(VAppTemplatesInOrg.java:56)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.functions.VAppTemplatesInOrg.apply(VAppTemplatesInOrg.java:1)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.suppliers.VAppTemplatesSupplier$1$1.call(VAppTemplatesSupplier.java:82)
    at org.jclouds.vcloud.suppliers.VAppTemplatesSupplier$1$1.call(VAppTemplatesSupplier.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Answer (score 0):

What version of vCloud Director is your cloud running?
From what I can tell jclouds only supports v1.0 and I get an error (but not the same as yours) as our installation supports only 1.5 and 5.1.

If your installation is more recent than 2012 (circa) chances are that it's newer than 1.0.